# How can i remove a field from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of object. For doing one opetation I need to remove few fields from this object and for some other operation I have to use the whole fields

But both of the array removing "regex" field. What is the mistake I am doing here?

```js
var newob = {};
var myObject = {
  "ircEvent": "PRIVMSG",
  "method": "newURI",
  "regex": "^http://.*"
};
newob = JSON.stringify(myObject);
delete newob.regex;
console.log("Test1", newob);
console.log("Test2", myObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `JSON.parse` so you can create the object back. Otherwise, you're trying to `delete` a property `regex` of a `string`, which doesn't exist.

```
newob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

`JSON.stringify` creates a string, you need to do `JSON.parse` to create an object from a JSON string.

For that object, you can use `Object.assign({}, myObject)` since it's a shallow clone.

```
newob = Object.assign({}, myObject);
// newobj = { ...myObject } // this will also work
```

Comment: thank you . This is working. But I did not understand the reason

Comment: See edit, but basically `JSON.stringify` creates a `string`. You need an object, that's why you need to do `JSON.parse`. But you can also do `Object.assign`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `newObj` is not a copy of `myObject` but a reference to it. Thus when you delete the filed of `myObject` you also see the change in `newObj`

To explain what I have said, look at this snippet:

```
> const a = {a: 1}
undefined
> b = a
{ a: 1 }
> a.c = 58
58
> b
{ a: 1, c: 58 }
```

You can copy the object like this:

```
const newobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

then changes on `myObject` won't affect `newobj`

There is an other problem:

```
newob = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

is wrong here because you assign you want an object but JSON.stringify returns a string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to map the input data and remove the `regex` from each of the objects in your input array.

```
const items = [
    {
        ircEvent: 'PRIVMSG',
        method: 'newURI',
        regex: '^http://.*',
    },
    {
        ircEvent: 'TEST',
        method: 'newURI',
        regex: '^http://.*',
    },
]

const newItems = items.map(({ regex, ...item }) => item)
```

A good way to explain what is happening above is

```
const newArray = array.map(({dropAttr1, ...keepAttrs}) => keepAttrs)
```

But should you want to remove the key from one object only you could

```
const myObject = {
    ircEvent: 'PRIVMSG',
    method: 'newURI',
    regex: '^http://.*',
}

const { regex, ...noRegex } = myObject

console.log(noRegex)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment